# How to detect missing dll in GAC in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, gac

I have a WPF application that references dll from GAC. Is there a way to detect (on startup), if some/all of those dlls are missing?

Currently, if there are missing dlls, the application just crashes. I'm overriding OnStartup, so I thought it could be possible to catch it there. I tried AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandeledException (based on this post [Catching missing DLL in XamlParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519813/catching-missing-dll-in-xamlparseexception)), but with no success.

Ideally I would like to show a simple MessageBox informing user, that there are missing dlls.

Comment: What's your code, cause the link you provide is the answer of your question

Comment: Override `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180638/working-with-appdomain-assemblyresolve-event).  Catch any errors and display in a message box accordingly

Comment: @GuilhemPrev I found the problem. I was using that missing dll in the OnStartup function. Once I removed it, the solution worked. However I have another problem. The MessageBox appears only briefly, before it closes along with the application. What would be the correct way to close the application only after user closes the MessageBox?

Comment: Could you show some code?  This will help us help you. [mcve]